# Is there a Klingon word for "curiosity"?

Tags: star-trek, translation, klingon-language

I was looking for a Klingon word for "curiosity" but I was unable to find one. In the dictionary, there are words for scientist (tej), science (QeD), research (Qul), analysis (poj), smart ('ong/vai), interesting (Daj), etc. But nothing reproducing exactly "curiosity".

I haven't checked the *Star Trek: Discovery* subtitles in Klingon yet.

Comment: Surely there must be a better forum for this kind of question.   Also, maybe something like "hungry for information"

Comment: Although this is broadly on-topic here, you might consider re-asking it on [ConLang:SE](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/), a stack aimed at speakers of constructed languages.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - it's [on topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8166/33591) here, but, Angelo, there's also a [conlang.se] site, where this might get a better reception. I'm not entirely sure why this has gotten downvotes, though.

Comment: There are a lot of words not in Klingon. As TPM hints, we usually construct an equivalent phrase.

Comment: @Mithrandir - I was hoping that the new ConLang stack would be somewhere that we could encourage the asking of these sorts of questions. They're effectively endless and since they (largely) relate to the real-world Klingon language, they're arguably off-topic here anyway.

Comment: @Valorum That is a good point, although it sounds like the OP has confirmed the word does not exist in *"real"* Klingon.

Comment: @zabeus - I'm on the verge of asking (via meta) if questions about real-world Klingon are even on-topic since it exists independently of Star Trek.

Comment: @Mithrandir:  I didn't suggest it as off-topic.  I merely said this can't be the **best** place to get an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I agree that the question belongs to the Constructed Languages site. Thank you for your comments, anyway :)

Answer (score 8):

For the most part, Klingon doesn't often use nouns to speak of moods, states or behaviors; it is more likely to use verbs.

For example, rather than saying "She is renowned for her cunning.", you would be more likely to see a sentence like **'ongmo' noy.** ("Because she/he is cunning, she/he is well-known."), using the verbs **'ong** ("be cunning, be sly") and **noy** ("be famous, be well-known").

There are certainly exceptions to this, with words for things like courage (**toDuj**), pride (**le'yo'**) and **QeH** ("anger"), but they are relatively rare.

It is also possible to nominalize verbs, but it's not really all that common, and often leads to unnatural-sounding sentences.

So, is there a known word for "be curious"? As it turns out, there is not. We are left trying to explain the state of being curious through the use of existing terminology.

**ghojqang** - *she/he/they is/are willing to learn* - formed from **ghoj** ("learn") and the volitional suffix -**qang** ("willing")

**ghojqangqu'** - *she/he/they is/are **really** willing to learn* - like **ghojqang**, but with the willingness

**poymar paQ 'e' tIv** - *she/he enjoys contemplating mysteries*

**yaj 'e' nIDqu'** - *she/he really tries to understand*

**pIj vuQlu'** - *she/he is frequently fascinated*

**reH yabDaj je' neH** - *she/he always wants to feed her/his mind* - There is a Klingon saying: **yab wIje'meH maSuv.** ("We fight to enrich the spirit."). Perhaps a studious person would rather say **qa' wIje'meH maHaD.** ("We study to enrich the mind.")

**ghung yabDaj** - *her/his mind is hungry* - I don't know if this would be common expression among Klingons, but I suspect it would get the message across.

If you really need a noun, you could try nominalizing one of them (i.e. **ghojqangghach** - "a willingness to learn") or using a relative clause (i.e. **DI'on'e' chIwbogh yab ghung** - "the characteristic embodied by a hungry mind").

Comment: This is an awesome answer, thanks for this. But I'm guessing this answer got downvoted because it doesn't cite any sources?

Comment: Thanks :) And, yes, that's probably the reason. I'll see about adding some sources later, but it's quite time-consuming to indicate sources for translations, since it's not something you can look up, save by looking up the individual words and grammar rules.

Answer (score 5):

Some composites that fit the definition:

*Sov'neh* (lit. knowledge-hungry), or

*Sov'nej* (lit. knowledge-seeking)

Comment: I'm afraid both of these are grammatically incorrect; Klingon doesn't have (regular) noun-verb or verb-verb compounds. Also, v'n is a forbidden consonant cluster. You can, however, use **Sov** as the object of **neH** or **nej**: **Sov neH.** = "She/He wants knowledge."; **Sov nej.** = "She/He seeks knowledge."

Comment: If you follow the universal rules of [linguistic lenition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenition), if you don't want the second of two consonants to change, you need to introduce a pause. If I'm not mistaken you can do that in Klingon with either a space of a " ' ".

Comment: Nope; the apostrophe is considered a letter in romanized tlhIngan Hol (corresponding to a glottal stop), and so adding it to a word is considered a spelling error, akin to writing "laptop" as "laphtop".Many words are

Comment: Many words are only differentiatd by the presence of a glottal stop, i.e. **maymo'** ("because it is fair") vs. **may'mo'** ("because of a battle").